# Android studio App icons are too close

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tv

I am playing around with the [smart mirror code](https://github.com/maxbbraun/mirror) and when I build and run the app on a Android TV AVD, the app makes all the info on the screen too close. The app shown in the Github website has is all neat and spread out but mine as shown below is all together.

Is there a setting I forgot to change?

[image: app running on android studio]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line in activity_home.xml to control your textSize
,the example set 30sp, you can set other what you need.

Example

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_1"
        style="@style/NewsStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/intra_group_margin"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/news_ap"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/icon_margin"
add >   android:textSize = "30sp" 
        tools:text="Obama, Sanders at the White House: Nice chat but that's all"/>
```

Comment: I will definitely try this when i get home. Another question I have is, assuming the mirror that is shown on the github page is using the same code to run it, why would the original poster's mirror have the icons all spread out neatly while mine are all compact? He is using a fire stick to run his APK and i assume it uses amazon tv. I would think android studio would see the size of the screen and compact or spread the icons around from that.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderIbarra Sorry that late for respond, I Think it have different Android API to support cause that the UI effect